# False display Excel column as vector

Tags: r, excel

My problem is that I cannot map a column from excel to vector correctly. Instead, I have units. My Excel table looks like this:

```
Name   Count
Darya    34
Tatyana  45
Kyle     56
Jimmy     99
```

I want to show data in column Count as vector this: [1] 34 45 56 99 but show; [1] 1 1 1 1 1
My code:

```
require(readxl)
basetable<- read.table("list.xlsx",header =TRUE)
colors = c('#4286f4','#bb3af2','#ed2f52','#efc023','#ea7441')
a<-table(basetable$`Count`)
as.vector(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `a <- table(...)`-call. If you type `table?` a help page is shown, explaining how it works (oversimplifying: counting occurrences of values, each value in you vector occurs once which yields 1 1 1...). Simply with `a <- basetable$count` or `a <- as.numeric(basetable$count)` you should get the vector you need.